# Properly formatting a big fractional equation [Line won't change]

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, align, fractions

On solving a boundary value problem I have attained two coefficients which are huge even after simplification. I have the Latex code from *Mathematica* which I tried copy pasting in *Overleaf* and a MathJax editor called *StackEdit*. The coefficient is is the form of a fraction and easily overflows the page. So I tried changing lines in both the numerator and denominator individually but `\\` failed to work in both the editors I mentioned above. The code is:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{32 e^{w \gamma } \left(e^{-w \gamma } \delta  \sin \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}+\beta \right) (2 \delta +\sin (2 \theta )-\sin (2 \lambda )) p_c \left(t_{\text{ci}}-T_a\right) \left(\delta  \left(e^{\beta _c} \cos (\theta )-\cos (\lambda )\right)+\left(e^{\beta _c} \sin (\theta )-\sin (\lambda )\right) \beta _c\right) \left(\delta ^2+\beta _c^2\right) \left(e^{\beta _h} \gamma  (2 \alpha +\sin (2 \beta )-\sin (2 \kappa )) \left(\alpha ^2+\beta _h^2\right){}^2+\alpha  p_h \left(-2 e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa )) \alpha ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\alpha )+2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h \alpha ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\alpha )+e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa ))\right) \beta _h^2 \alpha +\left(2 \cos (\alpha )-2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h^3\right)\right)-\alpha  \sin \left(\frac{\delta }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\delta }{2}+\theta \right) (2 \alpha +\sin (2 \beta )-\sin (2 \kappa )) p_h \left(T_a-t_{\text{hi}}\right) \left(e^{\beta _c} \gamma  (2 \delta +\sin (2 \theta )-\sin (2 \lambda )) \left(\delta ^2+\beta _c^2\right){}^2-\delta  p_c \left(-2 e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda )) \delta ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\delta )+2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c \delta ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\delta )+e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda ))\right) \beta _c^2 \delta +\left(2 \cos (\delta )-2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c^3\right)\right) \left(\alpha  \left(e^{\beta _h} \cos (\beta )-\cos (\kappa )\right)+\left(e^{\beta _h} \sin (\beta )-\sin (\kappa )\right) \beta _h\right) \left(\alpha ^2+\beta _h^2\right)\right)}{(2 \alpha +\sin (2 \beta )-\sin (2 \kappa )) (2 \delta +\sin (2 \theta )-\sin (2 \lambda )) \left(e^{2 w \gamma } \left(e^{\beta _c} \gamma  (2 \delta +\sin (2 \theta )-\sin (2 \lambda )) \left(\delta ^2+\beta _c^2\right){}^2-\delta  p_c \left(-2 e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda )) \delta ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\delta )+2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c \delta ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\delta )+e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda ))\right) \beta _c^2 \delta +\left(2 \cos (\delta )-2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c^3\right)\right) \left(e^{\beta _h} \gamma  (2 \alpha +\sin (2 \beta )-\sin (2 \kappa )) \left(\alpha ^2+\beta _h^2\right){}^2-\alpha  p_h \left(-2 e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa )) \alpha ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\alpha )+2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h \alpha ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\alpha )+e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa ))\right) \beta _h^2 \alpha +\left(2 \cos (\alpha )-2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h^3\right)\right)-\left(e^{\beta _c} \gamma  (2 \delta +\sin (2 \theta )-\sin (2 \lambda )) \left(\delta ^2+\beta _c^2\right){}^2+\delta  p_c \left(-2 e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda )) \delta ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\delta )+2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c \delta ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\delta )+e^{\beta _c} (\delta +\cos (\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\lambda ) \sin (\lambda ))\right) \beta _c^2 \delta +\left(2 \cos (\delta )-2 e^{\beta _c}+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \theta )-2 \cos (\delta +2 \theta )+e^{\beta _c} \cos (2 \lambda )\right) \beta _c^3\right)\right) \left(e^{\beta _h} \gamma  (2 \alpha +\sin (2 \beta )-\sin (2 \kappa )) \left(\alpha ^2+\beta _h^2\right){}^2+\alpha  p_h \left(-2 e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa )) \alpha ^3+\left(-2 \cos (\alpha )+2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h \alpha ^2-2 \left(2 \sin (\alpha )+e^{\beta _h} (\alpha +\cos (\beta ) \sin (\beta )-\cos (\kappa ) \sin (\kappa ))\right) \beta _h^2 \alpha +\left(2 \cos (\alpha )-2 e^{\beta _h}+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \beta )-2 \cos (\alpha +2 \beta )+e^{\beta _h} \cos (2 \kappa )\right) \beta _h^3\right)\right)\right)}
\end{equation}
```

Can someone have a look at this problem and suggest some workaround ?

Comment: Any decent intro to latex would have told you that `equation` does not support lines breaks. Use `align`  or `gather` instead, both from `amsmath`

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I will try your suggestion. Also even mathjax failed. Appreciate your input.

Comment: No, there is not mathjax here

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your inputs, but even on trying with `align` and `multiline`, I am still stuck. Any attempt at changing lines with the ` \\ ` line break throws an error

Comment: Drop all left/right constructions, they cannot! be broken across lines